# ListView Image Keeps Stretching Bigger

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I am displaying text and images in a ListView and the images are small but for some reason it makes all the images a little bit bigger so they are blurry why doesn't it stay normal size.

What must i change

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>



</LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: You can also check with using an ImageButton instead of an ImageView.

Comment: You can fix the width and height for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two attributes in xml of imageview:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

and

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with how you are warping your view elements, you have to keep in mind that with changing text length and image resolution wrap element will change your item view,

to counter that give relevant sizes and sometime you do have to restrict them to a certain size. And do use `android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"`
 to get image scaled properly if the resolution is bigger than restricted size of imageView or image will be clipped

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```